# Representation over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Are there any two inequivalent and irreducible $F$-representations of a finite group $G$ (where $F$ is a field of positive characteristic) having the same characters?

I can surely find an example in which the representations are not both irreducible, but I thought it would be nice to find an example in which both are irreducible.

Comment: Over finite groups, two representations are equivalent if and only if they have the same character

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/608614/81360) for instance

Comment: I missed positive characteristic! Sorry about that. The above does not apply.

Comment: I suspect that this might not be possible.  The fundamentally "weird" thing about representations over fields of positive characteristic is the existence of reducible but indecomposable representations.  We can't exploit that if we specify that the inequivalent representations must be irreducible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, characters of a collection of irreducible representations are distinct and linearly independent. This is Corollary 9.22 in Isaacs book "Character Theory of Finite Groups".

If you drop the irreducibility assumption then, in characteristic $p$, the sum of $p$ copies of any representation has the zero character. Brauer characters, which take values in the complex field even when the representation is in finite chracteristic,  were introduced (by Brauer) as a means of distinguishing between any pair of non-isomorphic representations.

Comment: Let $F=GF(3)$ and let $G=C_2$. Then an irreducible $F$-representation of $G$ is given by, e.g., the matrix $(1)$ (the trivial representation) and the matrix $(2)$ over $F$. But $2(2)+(1)=(2)$? Where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think you are wrong. But how does that contradict what I wrote?

Comment: Yep, you're right. I mixed up the linearity of matrices and linearity of characters. Thanks!